# Monitor and act on another process CPU consumption

Tags: linux, monitoring, process

I'm looking for away to monitor a specific process CPU consumption and act if the process didn't consume any CPU for the last X minutes/seconds on linux.

The use case it that I've a machine on EC2 (obtained using spot request) that I would like to power down if a given process on  doesn't really do any work (not crashed, just sitting in ideal) I would like to accomplish it from within the  machine without any of AWS services.

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) at the OS level.

But why would you want the instance to power off?

Comment: To save money, I've no use for it once its ideal